# Puppet and NRPE

Tags: nagios

Can I replace NRPE for Puppet, for managing? If the answer if affirmative, could somebody explain me which are the advantages between both of them?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

#### No

---

I think you are comparing two different things.

NRPE is an agent for remote monitoring.

Puppet is a configuration management framework, sort of like make(1) for entire Unix and Mac system configurations.

So, if what you want to do is install software and tweak configurations, Puppet is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

While you can setup NRPE to basically allow arbitrary command execution, it's both risky because of NRPE's simple authentication and tedious as it's difficult to manage lots of hosts this way.  Puppet is a tool for automating host configuration, which it is fabulous at.  If you want to just run a few commands remotely look into mcollective, pssh, mussh, dsh, sshpt, fabric, pdsh, pussh, clusterit -- there are endless others.  Even ganglia has a remote command execution framework.  Tools similar to Puppet are Chef and CFengine.

Answer (score 0):

DigitalRoss is correct. NRPE and Puppet are in two different spaces.